# My first WP development project - am I envisaging this right?

Tags: themes, cms

I've been asked by my friend to recreate his travel site, CMS style, in Wordpress.

His layout is something like this:

Home
About Us
-- Country landing page (with a featured tour, then links to the subpages below)
----- Tailor Made Tours landing page (landing page, then underneath, an overview of all tours in this country with "read more" links, each clicks thru to tour page) 
--------- Individual Tour page
--------- Individual Tour page
--------- Individual Tour page
----- Group Tours landing page (landing page, hen underneath, an overview of all tours in this country with "read more" links, each clicks thru to tour page)
--------- Individual Tour page
--------- Individual Tour page
--------- Individual Tour page
----- Special Interest Tours landing page (landing page, then underneath, an overview of all tours in this country with "read more" links, each clicks thru to tour page)
--------- Individual Tour page
--------- Individual Tour page
--------- Individual Tour page
----- Hotels in this country landing page (landing page w/overview of all hotels in this country with "read more" links, each clicks thru to tour page)
--------- Individual Tour page
--------- Individual Tour page
--------- Individual Tour page
Contact Us
Request a Brochure
Customer Care

There will be about 10 countries each with subsections as above. Each landing page would list all the individual tour pages, with a thumbnail image and a link to take you to the corresponding tour page. The tour and hotel pages would need to be added by his staff via the Wordpress dashboard/cms.

I am only just familiarising myself with Wordpress development and this is the way I see it:
- each country landing page would be a static page with links to Group Tours, Special Interest Tours and Tailor made tours.
- each of those tour landing pages (Group Tours, Special Interest Tours and Tailor made tours) would list posts within a corresponding category, for example China > Group tours would list all posts categorised under "China group tours".
- This list would be formatted to include the tour posts' featured image and a link to read the full tour post
- Each tour page would be a post - it would have a dedicated layout with custom taxonomies for including things like price. It would have dedicated places for the cms user to assign photos.
- There would also be a category for "China featured tour" and the cms user could choose a tour for this category which would appear as the country landing page's featured tour.

Is this the simplest way to go about doing that?? As I said, new to wp development, this would actually be my first project.. so just trying to get peoples input about how i'd go about it??

The actual site is here: www.sanyachinatravel.com

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job made for custom post types.

try something like this

1) custom post type of "Countries"
2) taxonomies of "Tailor Made Tours", "Group Tours", "Special Interest Tours", "Hotels"

[**More On Custom Post Types**](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress)

Comment: thanks very much Martin.. but can i ask in this case, how id get the landing pages to pick up whatever taxonomy was assigned and sort them?? For example, how would I get a Tailor Made Tours landing page for a specific country like China, to list all the posts under a Tailor Made Tour taxonomy, for china specifically? Also whats the relevance of having a "Countries" custom post type? Wouldn't I want a Tours and Hotels custom post type?? dont quite understand full answer.. sorry